# Solve highmaps-highcharts conflict when creating map, column and radar charts

Tags: highcharts

I am able to create highcharts column and radar charts in my Ruby on Rails app by requiring in the `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery3
//= require highcharts
//= require highcharts/highcharts-more
```

Then, I need to add a highcharts map. However, calling the map generation function `Highcharts.mapChart('container', {...` raises:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Highcharts.mapChart is not a function
```

I seem to resolve the error by replacing `//= require highcharts` with `//= require highmaps` and adding `//= require highcharts/modules/map`. Now I have both column chart and map. But removing `//= require highcharts` results in errors while calling radar chart: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined`. I cannot require both highcharts and highmaps together due to the conflict that raises:

```
Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #16: Highcharts already defined in the page
This error happens if the Highcharts namespace already exists when loading Highcharts or Highstock.
```

Trying to place `//= require highmaps` before `//= require highcharts/highcharts-more` fixes the error but raises two new errors: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined` and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateCenter' of undefined`.
How can I get column, radar and map together in the same app?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `Highmaps` and `map` module together. You can use the `map` modlue as a plugin with `Highcharts`:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gbduyLo9/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/getting-started

Comment: The map fails to create when I use `require highcharts` that requires the code that was automatically installed via `gem 'highcharts-rails'`. But it works when I replace the code in `highcharts.js` file with the one from `https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js`. Your fiddle answer the question but not your js manifest above

Comment: Could there be an issue with the file created by the installation via `gem 'highcharts-rails'`?

Comment: Hi @amo, Yes, it looks like the problem is caused by `highcharts-rails`. I think that you should open an issue on the github repository.